# Trying to figure out the issue with my code

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a problem with my code and try to find the error

I have already tried to use `let` instead of `var` but it still did not work. There is also no output in the console.

I believe the error to be within the `if (tylerdel == true)` of my code:

```js
if (command === prefixfile.prefix + `active`) {
    var tylerdel = true
    message.channel.send (`test`)
    if (tylerdel == true) {
        if (message.author.id === ("")) {
            message.delete (1)
        }
    }
}
```

It is supposed to delete a message if it comes from a certain person but I also need it to be toggleable.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: thats the strange part there is no error

Answer (score 1):

As per your code boolean variable `tylerdel` will always be `true` so there is no need to use this variable in your `if condition`.

```
if(command === prefixfile.prefix + 'active') {
        message.channel.send('test');
        if (message.author.id === '') {
           message.delete(1);
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with `==` (Equality) and `===` (Identity). 
[More info about the operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359547/11706893)

You should know what is "[Debugging](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)". You can try printing something in each `if` to see where is the problem.

Hope this helps you to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (command === prefixfile.prefix + 'active') {
    var tylerdel = true;
    message.channel.send ('test');
    if (tylerdel) {
        if (message.author.id === '') {
            message.delete(1);
        }
    }
}
```